# Subquery para pegar informações de linhas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql

tudo bem?

Estou com um problema: preciso retornar duas datas, que estão em uma mesma tabela, em uma mesma query. Alguém consegue me ajudar a como fazer isto?

Vou descrever o meu problema: Eu preciso retornar as datas do primeiro atendimento e a data da conversão somente dos leads que eu consegui converter.
Explicando melhor:
Eu trabalho com leads e basicamente há três status: Lead, Atendimento e Conversão. Na tabela1, eu registro em cada linha a data de registro destes status. Exemplo:

```
+--------+-------+-------------+------------+
| Código | Nome  |   Status    |    Data    |
+--------+-------+-------------+------------+
| 123456 | João  | Lead        | 01/01/2020 |
| 123456 | João  | Atendimento | 05/01/2020 |
| 123456 | João  | Conversão   | 10/01/2020 |
| 234567 | Maria | Lead        | 02/05/2020 |
| 234567 | Maria | Atendimento | 10/06/2020 |
| 234567 | Maria | Conversão   | 11/07/2020 |
| 345678 | Ana   | Lead        | 01/10/2021 |
| 456789 | José  | Atendimento | 05/10/2021 |
| 567890 | Abrãão| Atendiemento| 05/10/2021 |
+--------+-------+-------------+------------+
```

E o resultado que eu preciso é este e somente dos leads que tiveram conversão:

```
+--------+-------+------------------+-----------------+
| Código | Nome  | Data Atendimento |  Data Conversão |
+--------+-------+------------------+-----------------+
| 123456 | João  | 05/01/2020       |  10/01/2020     |
| 234567 | Maria | 10/06/2020       |  11/07/2020     |
+--------+-------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar a fazer isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ou seja, o que fazer é:

> "Selecionar o registro cujo Status seja 'Conversão'    **E**
> **Exista** um registro com o mesmo Código com Status 'Lead'"

Vou dar um exemplo que é basicamente igual ao que tem nessa outra resposta: [Select que exclui linhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/541025/select-que-exclui-linhas/541042#541042)

```
select d.codigo, 
       d.nome, 
       d.data DataConvesao, 
       dA.data DataAtendimento
  from Dados d
 inner join Dados dA on d.codigo = dA.codigo AND dA.status = 'Atendimento'
 where d.status = 'Conversão'
   and dA.status = 'Atendimento'
   and exists (select *
               from Dados d2
              where d2.codigo=d.codigo
                and d2.status = 'Lead');
```

Ou seja, a primeira query, com a tabela "Dados" e o alias "d" faz a primeira condição `where d.status = 'Conversão'`, **E** adiciona um `exists`, com a *subquery* que faz a segunda condição `d2.status = 'Lead'`.

Para resolver o problema da data de "Atendimento" que está em outra linha, adicionei mais uma vez a tabela "Dados" com o alias "dA", que faz o `join` por código, mas filtra por status "Atendimento".

Note que, no primeiro `select` foi usado o alias "d" e na segunda o alias "d2", isso porque é precisa validar se, para o mesmo codigo existe uma linha com "Lead" e "Conversão", que é feito através de um `join`: `where d2.codigo=d.codigo`

Veja um exemplo funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3x4GzV3RhHawHthYH7F9Nh/1)

Comment: Olá Ricardo, obrigado pelo seu apoio em me ajudar. Com esta solução eu consigo trazer as informações somente daqueles que tiveram conversão, porém o que eu preciso também é uma nova coluna com a data do primeiro atendimento (ou seja, quando o cliente foi registrado como status "Atendimento") que está em uma linha diferente. Sabe se é possível fazer isto?

Comment: verdade tinha faltado essa parte, atualizei aqui: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3x4GzV3RhHawHthYH7F9Nh/1  e vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Ricardo, muito obrigado pelo seu apoio! Particularmante não conhecia essa possibilidade de fazer um inner join com a própria tabela filtrando-a. Eu peguei a lógica do seu código e apliquei a minha tabela e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada, eu tento sempre por uma resposta exemplicando de forma genérica para que o conceito possa ser usado por outras pessoas em casos diferentes, mas sempre alguém negativa e não explica pq, mas bom saber que ajudei